# Using ThreadPool and Task.Wait inside an Async/Await Method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I just encountered this code.  I immediately started cringing and talking to myself (not nice things).  The thing is I don't really understand why and can't reasonably articulate it.  It just looks really bad to me - maybe I'm wrong.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessAsync()
{
     var userName = Username.LogonName(User.Identity.Name);    
     var user = await _user.GetUserAsync(userName);

     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((arg) =>
        {
            Task.Run(() => _billing.ProcessAsync(user)).Wait();
        });    
     return Ok();
}
```

This code looks to me like it's needlessly creating threads with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and `Task.Run`.  Plus, it looks like it has the potential to deadlock or create serious resource issues when under heavy load.  Am I correct?

The _billing.ProcessAsync() method is *awaitable*(async), so I would expect that a simple "await" keyword would be the right thing to do and not all this other baggage.

Comment: Yes it is very bad. Also this looks like code that runs in a web page, likey they did `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and actually meant to do [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) which is what you are supposed to do if you have background threads on IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange, but depending on what the author is trying to achieve, it seems ok to me to *queue a work item in the thread pool* from inside an async method.

This is not as starting a thread, it's just queueing an action to be done in a ThreadPool's thread when there is a free one. So the async method (`ProcessAsync`) can continue and don't need to care about the result.

The weird thing is the code inside the lambda to be enqueued in the ThreadPool. Not only the `Task.Run()` (which is superflous and just causes unnecessary overhead), but to call an `async` method without *waiting* for it to finish is bad inside a method that should be run by the ThreadPool, because it returns the control flow to the caller when `await`ing something.

So the ThreadPool eventually thinks this method is finished (and the thread free for the next action in the queue), while actually the method wants to be resumed later.

This may lead to very **undefined behaviour**. This code *may* have been working (in certain circumstances), but I would **not rely** on it and use it as productive code.

(The same goes for calling a not-awaited async method inside `Task.Run()`, as the `Task` "thinks" it's finished while the method actually wants to be resumed later).

---

As solution I'd propose to simply `await` that `async` method, too:

```
await _billing.ProcessAsync(user);
```

But of course without any knowledge about the context of the code snippet I can't guarantee anything. **Note** that this would change the behaviour: while until now the code did not wait for `_billing.ProcessAsync()` to finsih, it would now do. So maybe leaving out `await` and just fire and forget

```
_billing.ProcessAsync(user);
```

maybe good enough, too.

Comment: Very good response.  I'm thinking that a simple 'await' will be the recommended cure.  Do you agree?

Comment: @BigDaddy yes forgot the conclusion... as far as I can see `await` would be correct.

Comment: If the task wrapped in the QueueUserWorkItem is a long-running operation, does it change anything?

Comment: @BigDaddy still hard to tell without knowing the whole project. The code is broken for the reasons stated in the answer. And using `QueueUserWorkItem`, `Task.Run()` or simply calling the `async` method (with or without `await`) leads to the method being executed in a ThreadPool-Thread. It would only make a difference if it before was called via `Task.Factory.StartNew(...., .LongRunning)` so that it would have been executed in a dedicated thread while it now blocks a ThreadPool-Thread.

Answer (score 6):

I believe Scott is correct with his guess that `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` *should have been* `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. The call to `Task.Run` and `Wait`, however, are entirely nonsensical - they're pushing work to the thread pool and blocking a thread pool thread on it, when the code is already on the thread pool.

> The _billing.ProcessAsync() method is awaitable(async), so I would expect that a simple "await" keyword would be the right thing to do and not all this other baggage.

I strongly agree.

**However**, this will change the behavior of the action. It will now wait until `Billing.ProcessAsync` is completed, whereas before it would return early. Note that returning early on ASP.NET is almost always a mistake - I would say any "billing" processing would be even more certainly a mistake. So, replacing this mess with `await` will make the app more correct, but it will cause the `ProcessAsync` action to take longer to return to the client.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just a little confused.  The task being created is using 'Wait', but you say it will return early.  What's 'Wait' actually doing on that task in this context?  Is it similar to 'Result'?

Comment: @BigDaddy: `Wait` is just blocking a thread pool thread until the task completes. In this case, it does nothing useful other than use up a thread pool thread - you can get rid of the `Wait` (and the `Task.Run`) completely and the code would behave exactly the same (except using fewer resources). `Wait` is very similar to `Result` in that they both block the calling thread until the task completes. The action returns early because it's not waiting for the work queued by QUWI.

Comment: If the task wrapped in the QueueUserWorkItem is a long-running operation, does it change anything?

Comment: @BigDaddy: No. Regardless of how long it takes, QUWI is inherently unsafe on ASP.NET. (where "unsafe" means the operation may be terminated without notice)